# how to add a row to a df with one var=character(0)

Tags: r

I would like to add a row to an exist df `df`. the newrow contain the data as below, where V2=`nv`.

My problem is as `nv` is `character(0)`, how can I put it in as empty or NA?  Is it a good way to bind it together?

I tried `rbind(df,newrow, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`  as well as `df%>% add_row()` but could not get it to work. could anyone show me how to do this in both way, if it is possible? Thanks.

```
df<- structure(list(ID = "S12", 
            Sheet = "Reproductive", 
            TEST = "Y", 
             V1 = NA_character_, 
             V2 = NA_character_), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

nv <- character(0)

newrow<- nr<- list(ID ="S13",
              Sheet="Test",
              TEST= "N",
              V2= nv,
              V1= "removed")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can set the elements that have length 0 to `NA` and then `rbind`

```
nr[lengths(nr) == 0] <- NA
rbind(df, nr)
```

-output

```
 ID        Sheet TEST      V1   V2
1 S12 Reproductive    Y    <NA> <NA>
2 S13         Test    N removed <NA>
```

Or as @G.Grothendieck mentioned in the comments, if we don't want to change the original object 'nr', use `replace` (which internally  does the assignment in the function environment and thus it doesn't modify the object)

```
rbind(df, replace(nr, lengths(nr) == 0, NA))
```

---

Or another option is to extract `[` the first element, automatically returns NA if length is 0

```
rbind(df, lapply(nr, `[`, 1))
   ID        Sheet TEST      V1   V2
1 S12 Reproductive    Y    <NA> <NA>
2 S13         Test    N removed <NA>
```

i.e. we are using index which didn't exist and thus returns the NA

```
> character(0)[1]
[1] NA
> character(0)[1:2]
[1] NA NA
```

Comment: Great answer. If I don't set length 0 to NA, I got `Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  invalid list argument: all variables should have the same length`. Can you explain why we need this step?

Comment: or write it as: `rbind(df, replace(nr, lengths(nr) == 0, NA))`

Comment: @Stataq the reason is that data.frame columns all should have equal length as it is a list with equal lengths, whereas `list` can hold different elements with different length, thus a list element can be even `NULL` as well

Comment: What if I want to use `add_row ` for this task?

Comment: @Stataq Once you replace the `nr`, use `add_row(df, !!! nr)` or `add_row(df, !!! replace(nr, !lengths(nr), NA ))`

Comment: Sorry for a silly question: Why `!!!`?

Comment: @Stataq In `add_row`, the second argument is variadic `...`, By passing the whole named list, we can use the splice (!!! operator) as mentione d in the docs `Turning a list of inputs into distinct arguments. This is especially useful with functions that take data in ...,`

Comment: Or may also use `do.call` i.e. `do.call("add_row", c(list(.data = df), replace(nr, !lengths(nr), NA)))`